# Calculating the probability of at least one of $X_i \subset X$ using Inclusion-Exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

[image]

The Problem statement and the solution is mentioned in the image provided. Please explain me how the set is constructed and how do we get the probability in the form of the provided function $f(x)$ using Inclusion-Exclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing  that  we  have  $q$  of   these  sets  $X_j$  we  start  by
constructing the poset  for use with PIE. The nodes  $Q$ of this poset
are  subsets of  $[q]$  and  represent subsets  $T  \subseteq S$  that
contain the  elements of $X_j$  with $j\in  Q$ plus possibly  more, so
they could contain the elements of an $X_k$ with $k\notin Q.$ A subset
$T$ is represented by the term $z^{|T|}$  so that we will not be using
the cardinality  of the set of  subsets $T$ of $S$  represented at $Q$
but rather  a refinement,  namely an  ordinary generating  function of
these sets by the number of elements.

We now ask about the generating function  in $z$ of the subsets of $S$
that do not contain any of the $X_j$ as a subset. The weight of a node
$Q$ of the poset is $(-1)^{|Q|}.$ There  are two cases for $T.$ If $T$
does not contain any of the $X_j$ as a subset it will be included only
at the  base node $Q=\emptyset$  getting total weight  $z^{|T|} \times
(-1)^{|\emptyset|}  = z^{|T|}.$  On  the other  hand  if $T$  contains
exactly the  elements of the $X_j$  with $j\in P$ (plus  possibly some
others that  do not  contribute to  form a  different $X_j$)  for some
$P\subseteq  [q]$ where  $P\ne\emptyset$ then  it is  included in  all
nodes $Q$ that represent subsets of $P$ for a total weight of

$$z^{|T|} \sum_{Q\subseteq P} (-1)^{|Q|}
= z^{|T|} \sum_{k=0}^{|P|} {|P|\choose k} (-1)^k = 0.$$

We  see that  indeed the  only non-zero  contribution originates  with
those $T$ not containing any $X_j.$  We may now apply PIE knowing that
the generating function at $Q$ is

$$z^{|\bigcup_{j\in Q} X_j|} (1+z)^{|S|-|\bigcup_{j\in Q} X_j|}
= (1+z)^{|S|} \left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{|\bigcup_{j\in Q} X_j|}.$$

We thus  have for the  generating function  $Y(z)$ of the  subsets not
containing any of the $X_j$ by PIE the closed form

$$Y(z) = (1+z)^{|S|}
\sum_{Q\subseteq [q]} (-1)^{|Q|}
\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{|\bigcup_{j\in Q} X_j|}.$$

Now  a  set $T$  with  $|T|$  elements  represented by  $z^{|T|}$  has
probability $(1-p)^{|S|-|T|} p^{|T|}$ hence the desired probability
is given by

$$(1-p)^{|S|} Y(p/(1-p)) \\ =
(1-p)^{|S|} (1+p/(1-p))^{|S|}
\sum_{Q\subseteq [q]} (-1)^{|Q|}
\left(\frac{p/(1-p)}{1+p/(1-p)}\right)^{|\bigcup_{j\in Q} X_j|}
\\ = \sum_{Q\subseteq [q]} (-1)^{|Q|} p^{|\bigcup_{j\in Q} X_j|}.$$

We now know  the probability of none  of the $X_j$ being  a subset and
hence the probability of at least one being a subset is

$$1 - \sum_{Q\subseteq [q]} (-1)^{|Q|} p^{|\bigcup_{j\in Q} X_j|}
= - \sum_{Q\subseteq [q], Q\ne\emptyset}
(-1)^{|Q|} p^{|\bigcup_{j\in Q} X_j|}.$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{Q\subseteq [q], Q\ne\emptyset}
(-1)^{|Q|+1} p^{|\bigcup_{j\in Q} X_j|}.}$$

precisely as in the problem statement and we may conclude the argument
observing that increasing $p$ will  indeed increase the probability of
an $X_j$ appearing in $X.$

**Remark.** We can check the correctness of the formula for $Y(z)$
by comparing  the result of  enumeration to  the closed form.  This is
shown below, which also includes a plot.

```
with(combinat);

YX :=
proc(XL)
local XJ, S, q, Q, Y;
option remember;

    S := `union`(op(XL));
    q := nops(XL);

    Y := 0;

    for Q in powerset(q) do
        XJ := `union`(seq(XL[p], p in Q));

        Y := Y + (-1)^nops(Q)
        * (z/(1+z))^nops(XJ);
    od;

    expand(simplify(Y*(1+z)^nops(S)));
end;

YENUM :=
proc(XL)
local S, Y, T, idx;
option remember;

    S := `union`(op(XL));
    Y := 0;

    for T in powerset(S) do
        for idx to nops(XL) do
            if XL[idx] subset T then
                break;
            fi;
        od;

        if idx = nops(XL) + 1 then
            Y := Y + z^nops(T);
        fi;
    od;

    Y;
end;

YPLOT :=
proc(XL)
local S, f;
    S := `union`(op(XL));

    f := expand(simplify(subs(z=p/(1-p), YX(XL))
                         *(1-p)^nops(S)));
    plot(1-f, p=0..1);
end;
```

Some examples that were tested are:

```
> YENUM([{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {2,5}]);           
                           3      2
                          z  + 5 z  + 4 z + 1

> YX([{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {2,5}]);   
                           3      2
                          z  + 5 z  + 4 z + 1

> YENUM([{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {2,5}]);
                       4       3       2
                    5 z  + 14 z  + 14 z  + 6 z + 1

> YX([{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {2,5}]);   
                       4       3       2
                    5 z  + 14 z  + 14 z  + 6 z + 1

> YENUM([{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8}]);      
                    5       4       3       2
                18 z  + 45 z  + 48 z  + 27 z  + 8 z + 1

> YX([{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8}]);   
                    5       4       3       2
                18 z  + 45 z  + 48 z  + 27 z  + 8 z + 1
```

Here is a sample plot.

```
> YPLOT([{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {2,5}]);  

1 +                                                            HHHHHH 
  +                                                        HHHHH      
  +                                                      HHH          
  +                                                   HHH             
0.8                                                 HHH               
  +                                               HHH                 
  +                                             HH                    
  +                                           HH                      
0.6                                         HH                        
  +                                      HHH                          
  +                                    HHH                            
  +                                  HHH                              
0.4                                HHH                                
  +                              HHH                                  
  +                            HHH                                    
  +                         HHH                                       
0.2                      HHHH                                         
  +                   HHHH                                            
  +               HHHHH                                               
  +         HHHHHH                                                    
  **********+--+--+-+--+--+-+--+--+-+--+--+-+--+--+-+--+--+-+--+--+-+ 
0             0.2          0.4           0.6          0.8           1
```